# How to redirect to folder in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, browser

I want to redirect all the languages except the English for example, to another folder. If you are not english and you go to www.webpage.com/work/ you will go to www.webpage.com/xx/work

Now I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (aa|ab|af|am|ar|as|ay|az|ba|be|bg|bh|bi|bn|bo|br|co|cs|cy|da|de|dz|el|en|eo|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo|fr|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gu|ha|hi|hr|hu|hy|ia|ie|ik|in|is|it|iw|ja|ji|jw|ka|kk|kl|km|kn|ko|ks|ku|ky|la|ln|lo|lt|lv|mg|mi|mk|ml|mn|mo|mr|ms|mt|my|na|ne|nl|no|oc|om|or|pa|pl|ps|pt|qu|rm|rn|ro|ru|rw|sa|sd|sg|sh|si|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sw|ta|te|tg|th|ti|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|uk|ur|uz|vi|vo|wo|xh|yo|zh|zu) [NC]
RewriteRule .* www.webpage.com/en/ [R,L]
```

But I want to redirect from /work/ to /xx/work/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use back reference to captured text in `RewriteCond` using `%1`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (aa|ab|af|am|ar|as|ay|az|ba|be|bg|bh|bi|bn|bo|br|co|cs|cy|da|de|dz|el|en|eo|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo|fr|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gu|ha|hi|hr|hu|hy|ia|ie|ik|in|is|it|iw|ja|ji|jw|ka|kk|kl|km|kn|ko|ks|ku|ky|la|ln|lo|lt|lv|mg|mi|mk|ml|mn|mo|mr|ms|mt|my|na|ne|nl|no|oc|om|or|pa|pl|ps|pt|qu|rm|rn|ro|ru|rw|sa|sd|sg|sh|si|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sw|ta|te|tg|th|ti|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|uk|ur|uz|vi|vo|wo|xh|yo|zh|zu) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1/work/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (aa|ab|af|am|ar|as|ay|az|ba|be|bg|bh|bi|bn|bo|br|co|cs|cy|da|de|dz|el|en|eo|et|eu|fa|fi|fj|fo|fr|fy|ga|gd|gl|gn|gu|ha|hi|hr|hu|hy|ia|ie|ik|in|is|it|iw|ja|ji|jw|ka|kk|kl|km|kn|ko|ks|ku|ky|la|ln|lo|lt|lv|mg|mi|mk|ml|mn|mo|mr|ms|mt|my|na|ne|nl|no|oc|om|or|pa|pl|ps|pt|qu|rm|rn|ro|ru|rw|sa|sd|sg|sh|si|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sq|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sw|ta|te|tg|th|ti|tk|tl|tn|to|tr|ts|tt|tw|uk|ur|uz|vi|vo|wo|xh|yo|zh|zu) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?![a-z]{2}/).+)$ /%1/$1/ [R,L]
```

Comment: But there's more pages like /contact/, not all are /work/, I want that if you put /work/ you'll go to /en/work/ and /contact/ to /en/contact/

Comment: I get that: www.webpage.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/404//

Comment: I know what happens @anubhava it redirects, but when it is in en he do it another time, like /en/ then /en/en/ then /en/en/en/, etc.